# Creating a specific chrome window and use it as drop-down search window

Tags: linux, x11, gnome, wmctrl

I am using a simple script runs as "toggle.sh process1" which toggles visibility of  process1 if it exists and if it doesn't exist then it launches process1. It is really simple but useful. I use it for several applications such as terminal, kate, nautilus and lyx. (each works like a "drop down terminal" with an assigned shortcut in gnome)

However I need a more sophisticated way to achieve this with a specific Chrome window. This is because the restriction of this script is there must be one-to-one correspondence between process-name and window-id.

Any ideas how I can achieve this ?

EDIT :
To be more clear I want to toggle visibility of a window of chrome (for search purposes) and if it doesn't exists then create that window. One of the below might solve it but I couldn't find a way to do it : 
- Run an instance of chrome with a different process name and single-process option. (creating a symbolic link to chrome and naming it as "dropdown-chrome-4-search" wont work)

- For creation: create a chrome new-window change its title to say "chrome-4-dropdown". For toggling: in the script get the ID of the window with title "chrome-4-dropdown-purposes" to toggle. (Don't know how to do the first creation step in the script)

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/179454/ilker and http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/179455/ilkerk.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a bad workaround. If I run google-chrome --user-data-dir=XYZ
then XYZ will be in the process name (as a parameter) so it is possible to grep it from process list and get its window ID. It is not perfect since have now two profiles now. But signing to same user name helps to sync it... hopefully...